ANTLR4 - Token recognition error and mismatched input
I am fairly new to the ANTLR grammar. Here is what I have in my g4 file:
tptp_file               : tptp_input* EOF;
tptp_input              : annotated_formula | include;

annotated_formula : fof_annotated  |  cnf_annotated;
fof_annotated : 'fof('name','formula_role','fof_formula annotations').';

name : atomic_word  |  integer;

atomic_word : lower_word  |  single_quoted;

lower_word : lower_alpha alpha_numeric'*';

lower_alpha : '[a-z]';
upper_alpha : '[A-Z]';
numeric : '[0-9]';

alpha_numeric : '('lower_alpha | upper_alpha | numeric | '[_])';

...

I tried using the ANTLR parser on this test file that contains:
fof(an,axiom,p).

But I get an error saying:
line 1:4 token recognition error at: 'a'
line 1:5 token recognition error at: 'n'
line 1:7 token recognition error at: 'a'
line 1:8 token recognition error at: 'x'
line 1:9 token recognition error at: 'io'
line 1:11 token recognition error at: 'm'
line 1:13 token recognition error at: 'p'
line 1:6 mismatched input ',' expecting {'(', ''', '[1-9]', '[a-z]'}
line 1:12 mismatched input ',' expecting '[a-z]'
line 1:14 mismatched input ').' expecting {'(', '[', '[]', '!', '~', '?', '#', '["]', ''', '[1-9]', '[a-z]', '[A-Z]', '[$]'}

Can anybody please help me understand what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks.
I declaring lower_alpha as a fragment.

At a glance, these things are either wrong, or bad practive:
Too many literal tokens in your grammar
Doing ').' in your parser rule, would only match ). but not ) . (with a space between them). Try to minimize literal tokens in parser rules (unless you know what you're doing) and define them inside lexer rules:
OPAR : '(';
CPAR : ')';
DOT : '.';

and use those tokens in your parser rules.
No lexer rules
You have no lexer rules but try to create them in your parser rules. The rule:
lower_alpha : '[a-z]';

matches the text [a-z], not a lowercase letter. Do this instead:
// Lexer rules start with a capital and no quotes around it
Lower_alpha : [a-z];

Wrong quantifier
If you want to match zero or more things, you should not do Alpha_numeric'*'  but Alpha_numeric* (without quotes).
Fixes
Here is a grammar that works for the given input fof(an,axiom,p).:
grammar T;

tptp_file
 : tptp_input* EOF
 ;

tptp_input
 : annotated_formula
 | include
 ;

annotated_formula
 : fof_annotated
 | cnf_annotated
 ;

fof_annotated
 : FOF OPAR name COMMA formula_role COMMA fof_formula annotations? CPAR DOT
 ;

name
 : WORD
 | INTEGER
 ;

// TODO implement these parser rules yourself
formula_role : name;
include : name;
cnf_annotated : name;
fof_formula : name;
annotations : name;

OPAR : '(';
CPAR : ')';
DOT : '.';
COMMA : ',';
FOF : 'fof';
WORD : [a-zA-Z]+;
INTEGER : [0-9]+;
SPACES : [ \t\r\n\f]+ -> skip;


